# Text Editor I can use to edit GCode?

Tags: software-recommendation, gedit

I've been messing around with gedit and Geany which both support syntax highlighting for many languages but not for CNC/GCode. And neither have made it easy to make a custom language color scheme.

On windows I used Notepad++ to edit my GCode. It was pretty easy to set it up so that any G-command was green or and M-command red, and XYZ movements in Yellow etc... I'd like to do the same thing with Gedit but I don't know how. Help?

Comment: Emacs, of course! The one true editor. http://pixpopuli.blogspot.com/2011/01/syntax-highlighting-for-cnc-g-code.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is anything official from the Gedit project to support GCode, but I found a few from the community that should help you out.  They all offer .lang files and show you where you need to place them.  The first site says you should be able to customise the colours to match what you want.  Hope it works for you.

[wiki.LinuxCNC.org](http://wiki.linuxcnc.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?Highlighting_In_Gedit)

[CNC-Club.ru](http://cnc-club.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=80)

Answer (score 1):

[Emacs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EmacsHowto) has a the option for syntax highlighting based on [this project.](http://pixpopuli.blogspot.com/2011/01/syntax-highlighting-for-cnc-g-code.html)

Install Emacs with:

```
sudo apt-get install emacs
```